# Kill all Node.js processes on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

Using linux command :

```
ps -e|grep node
```

I'm getting a list of all running node.js processes. To kill one of them I need to execute

```
sudo kill -9 <processID>
```

Is there any way to kill all node.js processes?

Comment: `sudo killall node`

Comment: Thank you @akarienta ! Work's well!